# How can I determine which user triggered a promotion using the promoted builds plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm writing a Jenkins plugin that adds permissions to limit user access in certain scenarios. I currently have a bug where the plugin does not work as expected when a user promotes a build using the promoted builds plugin.

I have two users (devuser, adminuser) and two jobs (job-a, job-b). The devuser first builds job-a. Then adminuser promotes job-a which triggers a build of job-b.

When job-b is triggered via promotion, I try to determine who executed the promotion. If I look at the AbstractBuild's causes, **cause** is null and **causes** has an UpstreamCause which is the **devuser** and not the **adminuser**.

How can I determine who triggered the promotion? If I look at the promotions in the UI for job-a, I can see that **adminuser** triggered the promotion. I'm not sure how I can obtain a list of executed promotions for a build in a Jenkins plugin.

Thanks!

Comment: I should mention I looked at [promoted builds plugin wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin) that mentions environment variables. Those environment variables only seem to be available in the intermediate 'PromotionProcess' build, and are not available in __job-b__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not perfect, I came up with a solution that satisfies my problem.

As promotion builds are scheduled, I keep track of the build the promotion belongs to, and the user that triggered the promotion.

```
if (build.getClass() == Promotion.class) {
  Promotion promotion = (Promotion) build;
  RECENTLY_PROMOTED.put(getBuildId(promotion.getRootBuild()), promotion.getUserName());
  return new User(promotion.getUserName());
}
```

When the downstream job is scheduled, I check recently promoted for the build id, and get the user

```
UpstreamCause upstreamCause = (UpstreamCause) cause;
String upstreamBuildId = String.format("%s#%s", upstreamCause.getUpstreamProject(), upstreamCause.getUpstreamBuild());

if (RECENTLY_PROMOTED.containsKey(upstreamBuildId)) {
  String promotedUser = RECENTLY_PROMOTED.get(upstreamBuildId);
  RECENTLY_PROMOTED.remove(upstreamBuildId);
  return new User(promotedUser);
}
```